# How to backup color schemes from Windows 2000?

Tags: backup, colors, windows-server-2000

I'm planning on a migration of a virtual machine server which requires a completely new install, and I was hoping to retrieve the custom color scheme I was using on it so I could migrate it to the new installation.

I've tried this, but to no avail.

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/transferring-custom-color-schemes.1519780/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of messing around with the registry, finally found the solution.

In Windows 2000 custom color schemes are stored in the registry under:

```
HKEY_USERS\<ID corresponding to your user account>\Control Panel\Appearance\Schemes\<custom scheme name>
```